# What is new in SUPEE 8788 v2?

Tags: security, patches, supee-8788, supee-8788v2

As we all know, there is some issue in security patch `SUPEE 8788`, so magento has released its new security patch `SUPEE 8788 v2`. I am wondering there is **anything new for the after magento 1.8 or it is the patch for previous versions.**

And also want to know what could be possible error and what precaution we need to take care before installing this patch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SUPEE 8788 V2 fixes the following problems introduced by SUPEE 8788 V1:

- conflict with 1533 patch
- conflict with 3941 patch
- Unsupported data type N error in /lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php in 1.9.1.0 and possibly earlier versions

If you apply the patch V2 don't forget to follow this procedure:

- revert SUPEE-8788 v1
- revert SUPEE-1533 (if installed)
- install SUPEE-3941 (if not installed)
- install SUPEE-8788 v2

Comment: Addition: if you managed to install v1 on 1.9.2 and solved the conflicts yourself, you don't need v2

Comment: @fschmengler the v1 does not address the Unsupported data type N error so if you haven't created the lib files manually you still need to apply v2

Comment: Wasn't that only a problem with versions up to 1.9.1? I need to double check but don't think we had problems with our 1.9.2 installations

Comment: @fschmengler sorry misread 1.9.0.2 instead of 1.9.2